# Stopping TCP Adapter with Client ConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to stop a TCP Adapter with Client Connection Factory using a control bus command i.e `@AdapterID.stop()` 
The code for creating the flow is below:

```
 IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(Tcp.nioClient("127.0.0.1",3226))
             .serializer(customSerializer)
             .deserializer(customSerializer)
             .id("abc")).clientMode(true).retryInterval(1000).errorChannel("testChannel"))
             .enrichHeaders(f->f.header("abc","abc"))
             .channel(directChannel())
             .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(ConnectionFactory())
             .destination(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()))
             .get();

     theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("out.flow").register();
```

When I stop the adapter using control bus as:

```
 public String stopConnectionAdapter(String connectionName) {
    MessageChannel controlChannel = ac.getBean("controlBus.input", MessageChannel.class); 
    String exp = "@"+connectionName+".stop()";
    controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>(exp));
    return "STOPPED";
}
```

The Adapter is stopped but the following exception always get printed on the console

```
2018-06-04 11:09:45.551 ERROR 34860 --- [ask-scheduler-7] o.s.i.i.t.c.ClientModeConnectionManager  : Could not establish connection using conncr3, host=127.0.0.1, port=3226

java.io.IOException: conncr3, host=127.0.0.1, port=3226 connection factory has not been started
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.checkActive(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:873) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory.checkActive(TcpNioClientConnectionFactory.java:68) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:68) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:33) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.ClientModeConnectionManager.run(ClientModeConnectionManager.java:55) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

How can I stop this error and can close the connection without any exceptions and errors.

Also, What is the efficient way to handle(start and stop at runtime) these connection(Integration flow components) sequentially in expected way without any error?

Answer (score 1):

The `.clientMode(true)` is the culprit here. I am trying to stop the ConnectionFactory provided with id "abc" in flow definition
`.id("abc")).clientMode(true).retryInterval(1000).errorChannel("testChannel"))`

Now, I have added an id to InboundAdapter as below:
`.id("abc")).clientMode(true).retryInterval(1000).errorChannel("testChannel").id("test"))`

And using the control bus first close the connectionFactory then the adapter as
`@abc.stop()`
`@test.stop()`
the above error will be resolved.

But I still don't know the appropriate way to stop the IntegrationFlow in efficient way i.e I have to provide a unique ID to each component and stop one by one using Control Bus command.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't stop the factory; it's lifecycle is controlled by the adapter; just stop the adapter; there is no need to stop the other components.

You can also `stop()` the entire `IntegrationFlow` bean (`out.flow`) and it will stop the components.

Comment: Right. And the same Control Bus can be used on the matter.